# JQuery ajax get call and dropdown menus

Tags: jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have this code here that makes an ajax call and puts the data in a dropdown menu, but I have two values an id and name like so (this is from my `console.log`):

```
Name Gary 
Id 2 
Name Joe 
Id 7 
Name Kevin 
Id 5 
Name Paul 
Id 1 
Name Rocco 
Id 11 
Name Will 
Id 15
```

I am trying to put the id as the value and the name as the label in my dropdown menu:

```
$.get("/api/name/getNames", function (data) {
            var mySelect = $('#id');
            $.each(data, function () {
                $.each(this, function (k, v) {
                    console.log(k + " " + v);
                    mySelect.append($('<option></option>').val(v).html(v));
                });
            });
        });
```

but in my dropdown it returns

```
Gary
2
Joe
7
Kevin
5
Paul
1
Rocco
11
Will
15
```

How do I get the id as the value and the name as the label for my dropdown?

and here is the dropdown in question:

```
<label for="id">Name</label>
                    <select id="id" name="id" class="form-control">
                        <option>-- Select Name --</option>
                    </select>
```

Answer (score 3):

Is the 2nd `.each` loop necessary? If they are objects, you could do one `.each` loop like so:

```
$.get("/api/name/getNames", function (data) {
    var mySelect = $('#id');
    $.each(data, function (index, el) {
        mySelect.append($('<option></option>').val(el.Id).html(el.Name));
    });
});
```

Comment: I was wondering the same thing, but we don't (yet) know what the data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried amending the code like this?

```
mySelect.append($('<option value="' + v + '">' + k + '</option>'));
```

You don't need to set the value and label with functions, you can just drop them right into the tag you're generating.

Also, it's possible that you're iterating over the data improperly, but I can't be sure without seeing what you get back as data from your $.get call.

Comment: this is not that I am looking for, I am looking to have the actual id number as the value and the actual name as the label of the option.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to get you.  Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to read each line and the following line for getting it correctly

Here is the correct jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w57drLb6/

```
var mySelect = $('#id');
 var lines = data.split("\n");

   for(var i=0; i<lines.length; i = i+2)
   {
      mySelect.append($('<option></option>').val(lines[i+1].replace('Id ', '')).html(lines[i].replace('Name ', '')));
   }
```

*Please mark as answer if it answers your query*

Comment: I assumed that you got a plain text from ajax call